# Python: Erro no método .write()

Tags: python, método, sistema-de-arquivos

Escrevi um código que seria executado na minha Área de trabalho. O script iria escrever um texto em outro diretório. Para mudar de diretório, eu usei o os.chdir(), depois usei o subprocess.check_output() para executar um comando na shell e listar os arquivos da minha pasta e o método .write() para escrever em um arquivo de texto toda a lista de arquivos. Segue o código:

```
import subprocess
import os


dados = []

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\Teste')

retorno = str(subprocess.check_output(['dir'], shell=True))
dados.append(retorno)


arquivo = open('hello world.txt', 'a')
arquivo.write(dados[0])
```

O problema está na linha "arquivo.write(dados[0])", aparentemente só porque eu mudei o diretório no os.chdir(), o método .write() não funciona mais. Quando executo o programa, o arquivo hello world.txt é criado normalmente no diretório que eu especifiquei, porém não tem nada escrito lá. Alguém sabe o porque acontece isso?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você não está fechando o arquivo no seu programa para realizar as alterações. Para fechar o arquivo, utilize o método `close()` como no código abaixo.

```
arquivo = open('hello world.txt', 'a')
arquivo.write(dados[0])
arquivo.close()
```

Você também pode utilizar o `with` para que o arquivo seja fechado automaticamente.

```
with open('hello world.txt', 'a') as arquivo:
    arquivo.write(dados[0])
```